# Why does JS promise print all the resolve first then rejects second

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Why does promise print all the success first then the rejects after, even though i wrote the code for it to appear randomly

```js
var errors = 0;
var successes = 0;
var p1;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var num = Math.random();
    if (num < .5) {
      resolve(num);
    } else {
      reject(num)
    }
  });

  p1.then(function success(res) {
    successes++;
    console.log("*Success:* " + res)
  }).catch(function error(error) {
    errors++
    console.log("*Error:* " + error)
  });
}
```

OUTPUT

```
VM331:16 *Success:* 0.28122982053146894
VM331:16 *Success:* 0.30950619874924445
VM331:16 *Success:* 0.4631742111936423
VM331:16 *Success:* 0.059198322061176256
VM331:16 *Success:* 0.17961879374514966
VM331:16 *Success:* 0.24027158041021068
VM331:19 *Error:* 0.9116586303879894
VM331:19 *Error:* 0.7676575145407345
VM331:19 *Error:* 0.5289135948801782
VM331:19 *Error:* 0.5581542856881132
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It has to do with how asynchronous code works

`.then().catch()` - has to wait for the queue twice (hmm, I need to explain this)

`.then()` only once

Promises are by nature asynchronous ... in your code, when a promise resolves, the `.then` code is put on the microtask? queue  ... and processed in turn

when it rejects, as `.then` has no `onRejected` callback, so, the next handler in the promise chain `.catch` in your case is added to the microtask? queue - but by then, all the `.then` codes have been executed

try using `.then(onSuccess, onError)` and you'll get what you expect

```js
var errors = 0;
var successes = 0;
var p1;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var num = Math.random();
        if (num < .5) {
            resolve(num);
        } else {
            reject(num);
        }
    });
    p1.then(function success(res) {
        successes++;
        console.log("*Success:* " + res);
    }, function error(error) {
        errors++;
        console.log("*Error:* " + error);
    });
}
```

Another way (at least in native Promises) to get what you are after is

```js
var errors = 0;
var successes = 0;
var p1;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(() => {
            var num = Math.random();
            if (num < .5) {
                resolve(`${i} ${num}`);
            } else {
                reject(`${i} ${num}`)
            }
        });
    });
    p1.then(function success(res) {
        successes++;
        console.log("*Success:* " + res)
    }).catch(function error(error) {
        errors++
        console.log("*  Error:* " + error)
    });
}
```

This is because the setTimeout delays the resolve/reject

> ## An in-depth explanation

First things first ... you need to understand that `.then` is actually

```
.then(onFullfilled, onRejected)
```

and returns a Promise

next, `.catch` is simply "syntax sugar" for

```
.then(null, onRejected)
```

in fact, in most Promise libraries (before they went native) it is defined as

```
Promise.prototype.catch = function (onRejected) {
    return this.then(null, onRejected);
};
```

Right ... so let's look at an un-wound, simple version of your code - and only use THREE promises for brevity

```js
function executorFunction(resolve, reject) {
    const num = Math.random();
    if (num < .5) {
      resolve(num);
    } else {
      reject(num)
    }
}
let successes = 0, errors = 0;
function success(res) {
    successes++;
    console.log("*Success:* " + res)
}
function error(error) {
    errors++
    console.log("*Error:* " + error)
}

const p1 = new Promise(executorFunction);
p1.then(success).catch(error);

const p2 = new Promise(executorFunction);
p2.then(success).catch(error);

const p3 = new Promise(executorFunction);
p3.then(success).catch(error);
```

You can run that and see that it produces the same order of success and error

Now, let's change it up a bit, so we always get success/fail/success

```js
function executorFunction(num, fail) {
    return (resolve, reject) => {
        if (fail) {
          reject(num);
        } else {
          resolve(num)
        }
    };
}
function success(res) {
    console.log("*Success:* " + res)
}
function error(error) {
    console.log("*Error:* " + error)
}

const p1 = new Promise(executorFunction(1, false));
p1.then(success).catch(error);

const p2 = new Promise(executorFunction(2, true));
p2.then(success).catch(error);

const p3 = new Promise(executorFunction(3, false));
p3.then(success).catch(error);
```

This ALWAYS outputs

```
*Success:* 1
*Success:* 3
*Error:* 2
```

So we see the order you are seeing in your question - so far so good

Now, let's rewrite the .then/.catch in there expanded form

```js
function executorFunction(num, fail) {
    return (resolve, reject) => {
        if (fail) {
          reject(num);
        } else {
          resolve(num)
        }
    };
}
function success(res) {
    console.log("*Success:* " + res)
}
function error(error) {
    console.log("*Error:* " + error)
}

const p1 = new Promise(executorFunction(1, true));
p1.then(success, null).then(null, error);

const p2 = new Promise(executorFunction(2, false));
p2.then(success, null).then(null, error);
```

let's only use two promises, the FIRST rejecting ... we know that this will output `success 2` then `error 1` - i.e. in the reverse order we are expecting

So let's analyse what is happening

Because you're resolving/rejecting synchronously in the Promise constructor `executorFunction`

```
const p1 = new Promise(executorFunction(1, false));
```

is immediatelty a resolved Promise - fulfilled as 2 for p2, and rejected with reason 1 for p1, but it's never in a Pending state. So, when a promise is not pending (it's resolved, but that means either fulfilled or rejected, but the terminology has been mixed up, so I'll keep saying "not pending"), any "handler" is added to the microtask queue - so at the end of all that code, the microtask queue looks like

```
**microtask queue**
(resolved:2).then(success, null).then(null, error); // added second
(rejected:1).then(success, null).then(null, error); // added first
```

Now the JS engine, since there's nothing running anymore, processes the microtask queue (the head of the queue is at the bottom by the way)

- it sees a rejected promise(1), but the `.then` has no on rejected function, so the promise value carries down the chain
- `.then` returns this rejected promise with the original rejection reason
- this promise, because it has a handler (.catch in the original code) is added to the microtask queue

.

```
**microtask queue**
(rejected:1)>(rejected:1).then(null, error);         // added third
(resolved:2).then(success, error).then(null, error); // added second
```

Now the next microtask is processed

- It sees a resolved promise(2) so calls `success`
- **outputs `success 2`**
- `.then` returns a promise, because your success function has no return, this is `return undefined` and the promise is resolved as `undefined`
- this promise, because it has a handler (.catch in the original code) is added to the microtask queue

.

```
**microtask queue**
(resolved:2)>(resolved:undefined).then(null, error); // added fourth
(rejected:1)>(rejected:1).then(null, error);         // added third
```

- It sees a rejected promise(1) and there is an onrejected handler calls `error`
- **outputs `error 1`**
- `.then` returns a promise, there's no handler, so nothing is added to the microtask queue

.

```
**microtask queue**
(resolved:2)>(resolved:undefined).then(null, error); // added fourth
```

Now the next microtask is processed

- It sees a resolved promise(2, now undefined) - but there is no onSuccess handler
- `.then` returns a promise, there's no handler, so nothing is added to the microtask queue

.

```
**microtask queue**
**empty**
```

---

> ## why using .then(onFullfilled, onRejected) results in the expected order

OK, so now, if we write the code

```js
function executorFunction(num, fail) {
    return (resolve, reject) => {
        if (fail) {
          reject(num);
        } else {
          resolve(num)
        }
    };
}
function success(res) {
    console.log("*Success:* " + res)
}
function error(error) {
    console.log("*Error:* " + error)
}
const p1 = new Promise(executorFunction(1, true));
p1.then(success, error);

const p2 = new Promise(executorFunction(2, false));
p2.then(success, error);
```

The microtask queue starts, like

```
**microtask queue**
(resolved:2).then(success, error); // added second
(rejected:1).then(success, error); // added first
```

Now the next microtask is processed

- It sees a rejected promise(1) so calls `error`
- **outputs `error 1`**
- `.then` returns a promise, there's no handler, so nothing is added to the microtask queue

.

```
**microtask queue**
(resolved:2).then(success, error); // added second
```

- It sees a resolved promise(2) so calls `success`
- **outputs `success 2`**
- `.then` returns a promise, there's no handler, so nothing is added to the microtask queue

.

```
**microtask queue**
**empty**
```

---

> ## why adding setTimeout results in the expected order

Now let's change the executorFunction to add the setTimeout

```js
function executorFunction(num, fail) {
    return (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (fail) {
              reject(num);
            } else {
              resolve(num)
            }
        });
    };
}
function success(res) {
    console.log("*Success:* " + res)
}
function error(error) {
    console.log("*Error:* " + error)
}

const p1 = new Promise(executorFunction(1, true));
p1.then(success, null).then(null, error);

const p2 = new Promise(executorFunction(2, false));
p2.then(success, null).then(null, error);
```

Again, for brevity, let's use only TWO promises, and the first one fails, because we know that the output in the original code would be `success 2` then `fail 1`
Now we have two queues to consider ... microtask and "timer" - the timer queue has lower priority than the microtask queue ... i.e. when there's nothin running (immediately) then JS will process the microtask queue until it is empty, before even trying the timer queue

So - here we go then

At the end of that code we have

```
** empty microtask queue **                             timer queue
                                                        setTimeout(resolve(2))
                                                        setTimeout(reject(1))
```

Processing the timer queue, we get a microtask `(rejected:1).then(success, null).then(null, error)`

```
** microtask queue **                                   timer queue
(rejected:1).then(success, null).then(null, error)      setTimeout(resolve(2))
```

Oh, there's something in the microtask queue, lets process that and ignore the timer queue

- it sees a rejected promise(1), but the `.then` has no on rejected function, so the promise value carries down the chain
- `.then` returns this rejected promise with the original rejection reason
- this promise, because it has a handler (.catch in the original code) is added to the microtask queue

Oh, there's something in the microtask queue, lets process that and ignore the timer queue

```
** microtask queue **                                   timer queue
(rejected:1).then(success, null).then(null, error)      setTimeout(resolve(2))
```

- It sees a rejected promise(1) and there is an onrejected handler calls `error`
- **outputs `error 1`**
- `.then` returns a promise, there's no handler, so nothing is added to the microtask queue

Now the queues look like

```
** microtask queue **                                   timer queue
                                                        setTimeout(resolve(2))
```

So, I don't need to go on, right, because `error 1` has been output before the second promise chain has even started :p1

Comment: @Joromanda X Great answer.Please can you explain the above example, the one with setTimeout(), can you explain its execution, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm actually not 100% happy with the answer as is ... it's over simplified :p Let me work on it

Comment: How BIG can an answer be? I mean, I could describe this in great detail

Comment: Just wanted to know why it worked in timeout. Please could you explain that :-)

Comment: OK - I've edited with a **LONGER** explanation - the `setTimeout` explanation is right near the end - oh, boy, I hope I got it ***RIGHT***

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation ,  it cleared many concepts:-)

Comment: I hope the OP gets something out of it :p @amrendersingh - to be honest, I hope the concepts I've used in the answer are accurate :p

Comment: There's still something lacking in the answer, can't put a finger on it :p

Comment: I think I got it, basically initially the order in the queue is random. But when being processed all the rejects are re-added onto the queue after going down the chain, where as the resolved are processed with their success function. Still need to wrap my head around it a little bit. But thank you so much for the very detailed answer.

Comment: `initially the order in the queue is random` - nope, you haven't got it at all @TenzinChoklang ... the randomness in your code is does not put the microtasks on the queue in random order ... each iteration of your loop, a task is added in the order it is run ... in my example 1, 2 is in order, always ... I knew I should've gone with three promises in the examples .

Comment: Sorry my statement was vague, I was referring to the original code that I posted, which generated numbers (rejects and success) randomly. So in that sense it would be added to the queue randomly, meaning there would be no order like there was in the output. Is my understanding correct @JaromandaX

Comment: no, it would be added to the queue in order, the first one first, the second one second ... up to the tenth, regardless if it's resolve or reject

Comment: I think we both are saying the same thing. Im saying it would be added to the queue in order, by random i mean whether its a success or a reject. so the queue can look like this initially (success=1, reject =0) [1,0,1,1,0,0,1...] --> random @JaromandaX